# Which strange fruit is this?

Tags: species-identification, botany

Yesterday, my brother brought a strange fruit resembling Lychee (but much bigger in size). Here is a pic of it:

[image: Fruit]

When cut it, it had smell like banana and fibers were like of the chicken meat, though taste was more or less like banana (sorry have no pic of that).

Can someone kindly help me identify it?

Comment: As a complete sidenote, go search for "durian". It is a different kind of tropical fruit that you might not know about and it's fascinating. Especially how the taste/smell of it is commonly described.

Comment: The meat-like texture of jackfruit has led some people to use it as a meat substitute for vegetarians/vegans (though of course it's not really comparable in terms of macronutrients.)  See [here,](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/people-and-culture/food/the-plate/2016/07/jackfruit-sustainable-vegetarian-meat-substitute/) for example.

Comment: As a sidenote where are you from? This fruit and variants of it is pretty popular in S. Asia.

Comment: @J.E I don't think it's a durian according to wikipedia articles.

Comment: @AnonymousI yes, you are completely right, but that's why I used words such as "complete sidenote" and "different kind of fruit".

Comment: Yep, I've noticed that before I even started the comment but somehow unconsciously I wrote it anyways. My apologies for the mistake.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This appears to be a [jackfruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jackfruit). Jackfruit are a large, tropical fruit, commonly reported as smelling similar to banana.

[image: Image of cut jackfruit, showing bumpy exterior and fibrous interior]

Comment: Oh yeah!! Yes it is what it pretty much looked like from inside. Thanks a lot! I have seen it for the first time in my life.

Comment: Jackfruit are famously reported to taste like Wrigley's Juicy Fruit. Both seem to contain a lot of isoamyl acetate, as do bananas. So this all adds up.